# This is an interesting situation. Calling ajax delete function from another js file results

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, autoload

I have a page where I autoload records(infinite scroll) using a js and ajax file. What I want to do is add a delete function for each record using ajax.

The ajax/js function I have works great normally; but with this infinite scroll records loaded, I am having trouble making it work.

My page is rather complicated looking so here is a simplified version.

**Normal index.php without ajax delete function.**

```
ajaxload.php  // this is the file with query that loads the results of infinitescroll

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home page</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/infinitescroll.js"> </script>
    </head> 
</html>
<body>

<div id="results">
    // results of infinitescroll/ajaxload go here. For eg. 

    <div id="record">
        <h1>Title of record</h1>
        <p>Post description</p>
        <a href="delete.php" id="32">Delete</a>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**index.php with ajax delete function**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home page</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/infinitescroll.js"> </script>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $(".del-action").click(function() {
            var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
            var id = $(this).attr("id");

            $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "delete.php",
             data: {id: id},
             cache: false,
             success: function(){
                commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
             }  
            });
            return false;
          });
        });
    </script>
    </head> 
</html>
<body>

<div id="results">
    // results of infinitescroll/ajaxload go here. For eg.

    <div id="record">
        <h1>Title of record</h1>
        <p>Post description</p>
        <a class="del-action" href="#" id="32">Delete</a>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I do not get any errors when I try to delete the record. It simply doesn't call the delete.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that you attach click handler only on document ready. I'm assuming that your infinite scroll solution is loading new elements dynamically. Those new elements does not have any click handlers attached.

There are two solutions of this problem.

1. You may attach handlers after creation on new items
2. You may attach handler to element higher in dom structure which is static and listen to click event of his children. To create such handler you should use 'on' method (https://api.jquery.com/on/) with selector specified. For example:

   $('#parentElement').on('click', '.del-action', function() { //handler });